# Why do some photos taken with iPhone camera not have stored GPS coordinates?

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, iphoto

I have an app that allows a user to upload  photos from his camera roll only if the photo has stored GPS coordinates. I was wondering what causes some of these photos- taken on iPhone camera- to not have a stored location.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of at least four different ways to get photos without GPS coordinates associated:

1. Screenshots - seem to not have any geo information associated
2. Downloaded / imported photos - from Mail, or apps like 9gag for example.
3. Photos taken during active airplane mode

Most uncertain about the last one:

4. Photos taken where there simply is no GPS available, e.g. deep inside a mountain?

Comment: Please don't post answers to such off-topic questions. You are simply encouraging more bad questions.